# How does Vowpal Wabbit handle NA's or missing values?

Tags: predictive-models, vowpal-wabbit

I'm working on a problem that involves a large amount of NA's. How does VW work around this? Should I try to impute the NAs with colmeans or something similar before piping into VW format?

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on my answer:

Lets say the first line of your data is:

```
y, v1, v2, v3
10, 5, NA, 3
```

The VW string encoding of that line is:

```
10 |v1:4 v2:NA v3:3
```

As you probably discovered `v2:NA` doesn't work for VW, as the part after the colon needs to be a number.

An easy solution to this is to find `:NA` in your VW string, and replace it with `_NA`:

```
10 |v1:4 v2_NA v3:3
```

This will work fine in VW, as it will internally recode `v2_NA` as `v2_NA:1`.

This will allow the model to learn what happens when v2 is NA, and how that differs from the case where it is known.

---

You could impute medians, but it's probably a better idea to:

1. Compute a "NA flag" for each variable that is 1 when it is NA and 0 when it is not.
2. Omit NA variables from your VW training file.
3. Train on your dataset, omitting NAs and including flags.

This will let VW build a model that predicts one thing for an NA variable and another when it is present.

Comment: what does `omitting NAs and including flags` mean actually?

Comment: The problem with imputing column means is that you need to remember what the means you used were at prediction time.  VW uses a sparse encoding of the input variables, so my suggestion was to omit the NAs from the sparse coding.  I'll update my answer.